# Smarty error: unable to write to $compile_dir

Tags: php, apache, permissions, smarty, httpd.conf

I have Centos 7.2 and Apache httpd 2.4.6 web server, also I have a legacy php page with installed Smarty in `/var/www/html/project` folder. When I try to load the page I get this error:

> Fatal error: Smarty error: unable to write to $compile_dir '/var/www/html/project/tmp'. Be sure $compile_dir is writable by the web server user. in ...

I understand that tmp folder must have write permissions so I added it:

> chmod 777 -R tmp
>
> ls -l
>
> drwxrwxrwx.  2 user user    6 Jun 28 08:22 tmp

But the error still exists...

What else could be causing this error?

Comment: manly corrections of English...